# By learning to read and write upside down, what did I do to myself?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, motor, transfer

If you've ever read [Encyclopedia Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_Brown) books, you'll be familiar with the backwards writing in the back of the book that explains the solution to the case.

When I was in my mid-late teens (I don't remember the age exactly) I decided to teach myself to read/write upside down (and backwards?). I can read most text fairly well when the page is upside down (and have no problems with the upside down unicode text people post on Facebook), and I am able to write upside down with relative ease.

However, since developing that skill I have fairly extreme difficulties remembering how to write lowercase b's and d's, and I've had to use a trick I've heard dyslexics use and I remind myself that a 'b' points towards the end of a word.

I have no problems reading words with the characters, or typing them on the computer when I want a 'b' or a 'd', only when I'm writing it.

Did I give myself a very limited form of dyslexia?

Comment: Welcome to the site Wayne! I'll let someone with a bit more experience provide an answer, but to add a comment: dyslexia is much more complicated than just swapping `b`s and `d`s, and it not something one can "give" to themselves. Nonetheless, you ask a very interesting question!

Comment: I use a method for encrypting words using only numbers (2 digits is 1 character though), I have been thinking on putting effort on fluently read it but I am now worried about the drawbacks... As today, I can write pretty fast, but reading takes me some time per word (~2 seconds)

Comment: @ajax333221 I doubt you'd get much negative transfer, since numbers are completely different symbols. Though you might find that you read math as words ;)

Comment: Obviously, this is an old post. But you may be interested to know that I have been using "upside down reading and writing" to help visual dyslexics learn how to read.
I guess it works both ways.....
See http://pireading.com

Comment: you obtained a new skill thats what you did to yourself.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### Negative Transfer

A common scientific term to describe what you are talking about is called [negative transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_Transfer). I.e., where learning one skill actually results in lower performance on another skill. This is contrasted with positive transfer, when learning one skill facilitates performance on another skill. In general (although I don't have refs on hands) positive transfer is generally a greater effect than negative transfer. Negative transfer tends to be localised to particular aspects of the task (e.g., b's and d's).

For a extended encyclopedia entry see Perkins and Salomon's (1992) article on [transfer of learning](http://learnweb.harvard.edu/alps/thinking/docs/traencyn.htm).

#### Research on Mirror Reading and Writing

There's even research specifically on reading and writing upside down and back to front (e.g., see google scholarfor ['mirror writing'](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=mirror+writing&btnG=Search) and ['mirror reading'](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=mirror+reading&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=&as_vis=0)). I haven't read much of this literature.

To take but one article, Gottfried, Sancar, and Chatterjee (2003) discuss acquired mirror writing.

They note, perhaps relevant to your question, that:

> Young children, developmental dyslexics, and some healthy left-handed
>   adults may produce mirror text.

I assume that in the above cases (as opposed to your case where it is acquired with deliberate practice), writing in reverse is involuntary, in which case I suppose you could describe writing a few letters back to front involuntarily as representing a symptom shared with some developmental dyslexics.

As an interesting historical aside, they note that

> Perhaps the most celebrated mirror writer, Leonardo da Vinci,
>   generated over 5000 notebook pages in reverse.

So, you're in good company.

#### References

- Gottfried, J., Sancar, F., and Chatterjee, A. (2003). Acquired mirror
  writing and reading: evidence for reflected graphemic representations.
  Neuropsychologia, 41(1):96-107. [FREE PDF](http://pad2.wikihow.com/images/c/c6/Acquired_Mirror_Writing_and_Reading_226.pdf)
- Perkins, D. and Salomon, G. (1992). Transfer of learning. International
  encyclopedia of education. [FREE LINK](http://learnweb.harvard.edu/alps/thinking/docs/traencyn.htm)

Comment: Excellent answer, and now I have a term that actually describes what I did. An extra +1 for the da Vinci reference.

Comment: "I can't stoooq!" — Leonardo ba Vinci

Comment: Learning to type [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) degraded my QWERTY noticeably.  Now I wonder if this is a valid example of the "negative transfer" you've mentioned.

Comment: I have been using dvorak for over ten years and never felt a downgrade on standard keyboard. As they say, it's like learning another language: do you forget your first learned tongue? A useful reference for those interesed in dvorak is the [dvzine](http://www.dvzine.org/)

Comment: As an elementary school teacher for almost 30 years, I have had my share of students who struggle with reading. One of the first things I do with a struggling reader is turn the book upside down. Many times, the child, who has had difficulties reading, is able to read more fluently and accurately. I never knew how and why it worked, but it does. It is good to finally find some information that supports this "crazy" method that I have used time and time again.